# Pandas: value_counts into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
a       b        c       d       e
1       0        1       0       0
0       1        0       1       1
0       0        0       1       1
1       0        0       1       1
0       0        0       1       1
```

I need to convert this table so that for each of the columns, I get the count of 0s and 1s. I need the following table:

```
fields    count_1     count_0
------------------------------
a          2           3
b          1           4
c          1           4
d          4           1
e          4           1
```

I know that if I use the value_counts(), I would return the count of each value for me. However, I really don't know how to create this table. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `sum` and `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([(df==0).sum().rename('count_0'), df.sum().rename('count_1')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   count_0  count_1
a        3        2
b        4        1
c        4        1
d        1        4
e        1        4
```

## Timings

```
%timeit df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).transpose().add_prefix('count_')
```

> 6.4 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit df.stack().groupby(level=[1]).value_counts().unstack().add_prefix('count_')
```

> 2.78 ms ± 69.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
df_out = pd.DataFrame([
    [x.strip() for x in df.columns], sum(df.values == 1), sum(df.values == 0)
]).T
df_out.columns = ['fields', 'count_1', 'count_0']
```

> 1.15 ms ± 27.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit pd.concat([(df==0).sum().rename('count_0'), df.sum().rename('count_1')], axis=1)
```

> 1.09 ms ± 9.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a column-wise apply of `value_counts`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).transpose().add_prefix('count_')

   count_0  count_1
a        3        2
b        4        1
c        4        1
d        1        4
e        1        4
```

---

Or, similarly using `stack` and `unstack`:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=[1]).value_counts().unstack().add_prefix('count_')

   count_0  count_1
a        3        2
b        4        1
c        4        1
d        1        4
e        1        4
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [x.strip() for x in df.columns], sum(df.values == 1), sum(df.values == 0)
]).T

df.columns = ['fields', 'count_1', 'count_0']
```

---

```
  fields count_1 count_0
0      a       2       3
1      b       1       4
2      c       1       4
3      d       4       1
4      e       4       1
```